# How Would I Create Bindings to a GUI toolkit like GTK, Tk, or Qt for a Programming Language?

Tags: gui, binding

The title says it all.  How would I, in theory, create a binding for different GUI toolkits for a programming language that has no GUI bindings.  I ask because I want to experiment with this sometime in the future.

Comment: This question is way too broad. What is the problem you are trying to solve, and which programming language are we talking about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use the language's [foreign function interface (FFI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface) to call out to the C bindings. You can look at how other languages have done this, like [pygobject](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/pygobject). It's not easy though. You have to understand the C implementation very well, and your FFI very well. If your goal is to learn how to do the bindings, it might be worth it. If your goal is to create a GUI desktop application in your language, there are probably easier options.